# Reading from text file - Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to familiarize myself with objective C, and my current goal is to read a list of items in a text file and store them in a NSString array.

Currently this is what I have:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"txt"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                             length:[data length]
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString* delimiter = @"\n";
listArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];
```

I am not sure if this matters, but `myList.txt` is in my Supporting Files.

At the moment, I only have one item in my list. However I am unable to store even that 1 item into my `listArray`.

I am sure it is something silly that I am missing, I am just new to Objective C.

**EDIT:**
I apologize for not mentioning this earlier. I AM NOT receiving any sort of error. My array is just null.

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. I am not getting an error, my array is just null. Later I want to do some comparing to the array of loaded list items.

Comment: Is your "myList.txt" file listed within the Copy Bundle Resources section of your Build Phase? (Click on your app's target on the main project view.)

Comment: log the file path, and the data (at least length) and the string. Consider using NSString initWithData:encoding: instead of initWithBytes:...

Comment: I'd suggest either using the debugger or NSLog to verify that you're are getting `data` and `string` from your creation routines first.   If `string` is null, you'll get nothing back from the `componentsSeparatedByString:` call.

Comment: I am getting a null value for my filepath. I have triple checked to make sure my file name is correct.

Comment: Click on your project, the target, then the "Build Phases" tab, search for `myList.txt` let us know if it appears and in what section.

Comment: It appears in the Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: I actually have solved my issue thanks to you guys. My file was in the bundle resources, but was "myList". Not myList.txt. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a little simplification which might solve your problem since I can't say what your problem is. From the information I'm not sure if you are getting the proper file contents when reading it in or not.

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", error.localizedDescription);

// maybe for debugging...
NSLog(@"contents: %@", fileContents);

NSArray *listArray = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"items = %d", [listArray count]);
```

Comment: Cocoa requires that you check the direct return value before using the `NSError`, not whether the error is `nil`. The error is [guaranteed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) to be valid if the method indicates failure, but the reverse -- that it will be `nil` for success -- is _not_ guaranteed, even if you set it to `nil` beforehand.

Comment: Josh, what you wrote is accurate, but you'll notice I just spit out the message if I got an `NSError` back. I was not trying to determine success or failure of the call and did not modify my code flow based on the results of the check. I would have used `if (fileContents == nil && error)` if I been intending to check error state. That said, it seems reasonable to highlight the distinction for someone who might convert the `if` into a success check without realizing the implications.

Comment: filePath should be lowercase (filepath) in stringWithContentsOfFile ^^

Answer (score 3):

If the content of the file is just like:

```
[{"Title":"20","Cost":"20","Desc":""},{"Title":"10","Cost":"10.00","Desc":""},{"Title":"5","Cost":"5.00","Desc":""}]
```

try this

```
-(id)readFromDocumentDBFolderPath:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile])
    {
        NSError *error= NULL;
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
        id resultData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        if (error == NULL)
        {
            return resultData;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```