# Xcode only reading some of Resource TXT file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, plaintext

In my iOS app, I have it set to read a .txt file from the resources folder, and create an NSArray from each line of text.  However, when I try this, the NSArray returns empty.

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LUKEQUESTIONSPLAINTEXTFILE" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                                length:[data length]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *listArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"HERE IT IS: %@", listArray);
```

Moreover, if I do a lot for the entire string, it stops after the very first line break. What am I doing wrong? The file is only 214 bytes.

Comment: It should be `\n` not `/n`...

Comment: @l'L'l same result, updated code to reflect the change.  Plus, even when I log the value 'string' I only get until the first line break, as though it can't see anything after a line break.

Comment: Maybe try instead using `NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];` then 
`NSArray *listArray = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];`

Comment: This may be a better approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/16223139/6257435

Comment: @DonMag I did that, and contents came back blank, but the count for the array did show 3072, it's just not showing the array in NSLog is maybe the issue?  It's been a pain, I'm just trying to get this text file converted into a PLIST file, where each question and answer choice in the file is a entry in a dict file of the PLIST

Comment: @user717452 - I just did a quick test using the code in the answer I linked to, and it worked fine. Is it possible your `.txt` file is malformed?

Comment: It seems to be the issue that someone marked with it truncating text, as I can manually pull an objectAtIndex of the array up.....just wish I had been aware of this before debugging for over an hour lol.  SMH oh well